# add tags whose content will be ignored during conversion using pandoc - possible?

Tags: pandoc

I want to convert a special type of LaTeX file (including R code) into an special type of markdown file (including the same R code). Using pandoc I get an error as the R code contains parts that are interpreted as LaTeX syntax (such as dollar signs) which will cause an error using pandoc. A simple solution to this would be to entirely ignore the part between the R code tags during conversion.

**Question**: Is it possible to define tags whose content will be excluded during conversion using pandoc. E.g. convert everything except the text between `<<>>=` and `@`?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. Just use '\begin{verbatim}' and '\end{verbatim}'

```
Code:

\begin{verbatim}
val i:Int = 3

def main(){
    i+1
}
\end{verbatim}

Text. Text. Text.
```

Try this example at http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/try/